# Java HTTP Request Fail

Tags: java, url, httprequest, urlconnection

I'm doing one java query with http on some search engines and here is the code of two classes:

```
public EventSearch(){

    btsearch.addActionListener(this);

}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        if(e.getSource()==btsearch){


            try {
                HttpRequest http = new HttpRequest(CatchQuery());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HTTP request failure.");
            }   
            this.dispose();
        }

    }

    public String CatchQuery(){
        query=txtsearch.getText();
        return query;
    }
```

and

```
public class HttpRequest extends EventSearch 
{
    String query;
    URL url;

public HttpRequest(String query) throws IOException{
    // Fixed search URL; drop openConnection() at the end

    try {
        url = new URL("http://google.com/search?q="+query);
        System.out.println(CatchQuery());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to search the requested URL");
    }


    // Setup connection properties (this doesn't open the connection)
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

    // Setup a reader
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    // Read line by line
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println (line);
    }

    // Close connection
    reader.close();
}
```

The thing is - There are no errors regarding the code but the request is stucked. I don't receive any sort of message on my console our debug. I'm thinking of any sort of memory error since I'm working with strings but anyone has any idea of whats going wrong on?

thank you

Edit One:

```
public String CatchQuery(){
            query=txtsearch.getText();
            return query;
        }
```

CatchQuery Simple catch the query of the txtsearch (field).

Edit Two: [Topic Solved]

Comment: What does the `CatchQuery()` method do?

Comment: @BackSlash thanks for repply, take a look at edit one that I made. its quite simple to catch the string.

Comment: What is `txtsearch.getText()` returning?

Comment: You're not getting messages because you've hidden them - in your catches, print the stack trace with `e.printStackTrace()` or, minimally, write `e.getMessage()` to System.out.

Comment: @BackSlash String javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.getText()



getText
public String getText()
Returns the text contained in this TextComponent. If the underlying document is null, will give a NullPointerException. Note that text is not a bound property, so no PropertyChangeEvent is fired when it changes. To listen for changes to the text, use DocumentListener.
Returns:
the text 
Throws: 
NullPointerException - if the document is null

Comment: @VictorOliveira I do know what it does, i want to know the string it is returning, what string do you input?

Comment: @RayStojonic What do you mean by "You've hidden them" - I mean, the system println is just to debug and see if its catching the query correctly, and when I say the nothing is showing up its because when I execute the program after request the search it just stops to respond and gives no answer on console...

Comment: @VictorOliveira Ray means that every catch block you have is getting rid of the exception thrown, add `e.printStackTrace()` to every catch block and you will see which specific exception is being thrown and where

Comment: @BackSlash Sorry, I misssunderstood you, anyway; I'm typing simple text as "Hello World" and the purpose is to request the connection on google input "Hello World" make on search - the URL connection is working fine. I received the google xml code in some of my tests but until that point wans't working the query even though I inputed the "Hello World". After some changes the query might be working but I can't really see cos it's returning nothing, just stucking

Comment: @VictorOliveira you have to print the exception stack trace, see this pastebin, it refers to your 2 `try-catch`es: http://pastebin.com/qsUwvRtu

Comment: A: You don't know why it's failing because you're ignoring the exception's message, B: a URL cannot have a space in it, 'hello world' is invalid, either 'hello+world' or 'hello%20world' would be valid. Look into URL Encoding. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I've made some progress here, the server is returning error 403 - I will study this more to see if I can close the topic ;)

Comment: @VictorOliveira try just changing `url = new URL("http://google.com/search?q="+query);` to `url = new URL("http://google.com/search?q="+URLEncoder.encode(query));` Does it work?

Comment: @BackSlash Awesome catch this URLEncoder, thank you - it's working but by this I mean, its enconding the URL in one correct format. But I receiving from google Error 403 - Manually making the query with the URL works good, so that means that google won't accept one request through java??

Comment: `http://google...` isn't a complete URL, try `http://www.google...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `"http://google.com/search?q="+query` should be `"http://google.com/search?q="+URLEncoder.encode(query)`, query url needs to be encoded before opening a connection, so that unsupported characters are converted to url-friendly characters
2. Google does not accept bot connections, you should use the [Google Java API](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) to perform searches properly

**UPDATE**

Google does not accept connections without the User Agent header, so you have to edit the `HttpRequest` class to set the user agent after creating the connection:

```
// Setup connection properties (this doesn't open the connection)
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723 Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
```

It works for me, test it and tell me if it works for you too.

Note: from [Google ToS](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66357):

> ### Automated queries
>
> Google's Terms of Service do not allow the sending of automated queries of any sort to our system without express permission in advance from Google. Sending automated queries consumes resources and includes using any software (such as WebPosition Gold) to send automated queries to Google to determine how a website or webpage ranks in Google search results for various queries. In addition to rank checking, other types of automated access to Google without permission are also a violation of our Webmaster Guidelines and Terms of Service.

Comment: Now I'm asking myself.. You used especific informations such as mozila, linux and so on, I need something for a general app, so wouldn't be better use the google API?

Comment: @VictorOliveira Specific informations are just headers, you can set them to whatever you want, i.e. for me (i'm using google chrome) it is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36`. And yes, it would be better to use Google APIs, mine was just a suggestion on how to get your code to work and download the search results without getting the 403 error

Comment: Will take a look on this as soon as possible, ty!