# HTTP Request with Java - Yahoo

Tags: java, http, httprequest, yahoo

I made one research at:

1. http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/important-api-updates-changes-8060.html
2. http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/
3. http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ysearchboss/msearch?query=http+request&submit=Search&charset=windows-1252
4. http://developer.yahoo.com/java/howto-reqRestJava.html

I found that in 2008 Yahoo made one change at the http method for java programming, that used to be made i.e. for the word "umbrella" with:

"String request = "http://api.search.yahoo.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=umbrella&results=10";"

regarding with:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        GetMethod method = new GetMethod(request);


        // Send GET request

        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
```

and so on..Now they have the BOSS search API but until now I found nothing about:

"How to HTTP request from java in Yahoo search engine?"

ps: just remebering that yahoo make some sort of encrypted search and things like urlencoder.encode(query) won't work.

Anyone has something for me about this? Thanks in advance! =]

Edit One: Found this "http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/codeexamples.html#oauth_java" at yahoo developer and I'm trying to answer my own question.

**Edit One:**

```
try {


    WebSearch ws = new WebSearch();

    ws.search(userQuery);

    List<WebSearchResult> results = ws.getResults();

    for(WebSearchResult result : results){
         System.out.println(result.getTitle());
    }

    // Setup connection properties (this doesn't open the connection)
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723 Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)");

    //Setup a reader
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    //Read line by line
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println (line);
    }
    //Close connection
    reader.close();
}
```

Error reported on console:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   com.jellymold.boss.util.BOSSException: IO Exception   at
>   com.jellymold.boss.WebSearch.search(WebSearch.java:103)   at
>   com.jellymold.boss.WebSearch.search(WebSearch.java:66)    at
>   com.sh.st.HttpRequest.(HttpRequest.java:33)     at
>   com.sh.st.EventSearch$1.actionPerformed(EventSearch.java:32)  at
>   javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: IO Exceptionboss.yahooapis.com   at
>   com.jellymold.boss.util.HTTPRequestImpl.sendGetRequest(HTTPRequestImpl.java:62)
>     at com.jellymold.boss.WebSearch.search(WebSearch.java:92)   ... 39
>   more

**Edit Two**:

```
 public int sendGetRequest(String url) throws IOException{
        //int ret = 500;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723 Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)");
            // ret = uc.getResponseCode();
           // if(200==ret){
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
              //  }
                rd.close();
                setResponseBody(sb.toString());
            }
        }catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            throw new IOException(url+" is not valid");
        }catch (IOException ie) {
            throw new IOException("IO Exception" + ie.getMessage());
        }
        return ret=0;
    }
```

Check out this piece of code that comes from the javaboss API - I made changes on it to setup the reader - the value that comes from uc.getResponseCode(); is zero. it's in the "Main" class name bosssearch. That means that if is always different from 200 and the return value is always zero...I think that might crashs the code but now I need to export the java file as an jar to replace it and since its from outside of the project I'm having some problems with it, what do you think?

Comment: I can't get the point. You want to be able to search for a term on yahoo search?

Comment: @BackSlash yes, but working inside one java application - the result using normal methods return error 403 or 401 - Unauthorised acess

Comment: Still solving the problem. I started to use the code provided from http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/codeexamples.html - with this code and imports that is requested on the site, I found another bug that can be solved downloading the codec from this site  http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi and adding it to the build path of the project. Now my programm is returning an authentication from Yahoo which means it's at least acessing the http request - As soon as I conclude the search request I will post the entire solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [javaboss](https://code.google.com/p/javaboss/) to perform searches to the Yahoo! search engine:

```
WebSearch ws = new WebSearch();

ws.search("your_search_keywords_here");

System.out.println("Total hits : " + ws.getTotalResults());

//get a list of results
List<WebSearchResult> results = ws.getResults();

//iterate over the list and print every result title
for(WebSearchResult result : results){
     System.out.println(result.getTitle());
}
```

However, you should set the User Agent to make this type of requests without getting the 403 error, [as i explained in the answer to one of your previous questions (Google search from java request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259959/java-http-request-fail#answer-17260723)

Comment: Trying, give me some minutes please

Comment: Hey backslash, My search in google engine is working good now, but I still need to run some tests in Yahoo - this code is compiling but it's not fully working, I need to research more to see whats going wrong before ask for more help if its needed; don't like to make me as lazy..but ty very much, soon as possible I will be back to see if this answer is appropriate to mark as correct and send forward regarding to my case ;) TY!

Comment: @VictorOliveira Try setting the user agent as i did in your google question, it should work and you won't have to use javaboss

Comment: Still trying to solve, check out edit one. I tryed to check the javaboss code and inside the exceptions I found nothing that would explain why this is happening - the code and the paratemeters are fine, it's not like one syntax or lexical problem - I think something is missing..

Comment: I realised here that the IOException comes from HTTP Error 500 - exception 103 line from websearch javaboss code..it's one generic error without specific diagnostic =/ what a headache

Comment: Tracking the code I realised that it's openning two openconnection() buffreader() and so on, that's proably the error - I'm tracking now how to pass the user agente to remove the duplication of the methods since it's being already called by ws.search()

Comment: @VictorOliveira well, the url you are trying to access is printing _The service has been shut down. For further details, please see the Deprecated Services blog post http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/08/api_updates_and_changes_

Comment: were u saw this print? cos Using the java boss which the name already says it uses the new boss api search from Yahoo - I read this article few days ago and that's what I'm trying to solve now; This shutdown method comes from this link "http://api.search.yahoo.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=umbrella&results=10" which was used by the older API